# Remove Header and Footer from CSV file in pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pyspark

I am working on a requirement to upload the file from a onprem server to sharepoint in pyspark/python. Before uploading it is required to remove the header and footer from the csv file.
The challenge here is that the header content is dynamic and can have any number of rows and so is the footer.

[image]

In the above image the yellow shaded ones are dynamic and can increase or decrease. The Final CSV file should contain only the rows from 5 to 7. How can this be achieved.
Please advise
Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you determine that the header and footers are not part of the data?  Is it just that they are a single column?

Comment: If your header or footer starts with a specific char, you can use `comment` option on csv read (`spark.read.csv('file.csv', comment='#')`). or if you know the schema of data, you can do something like `spark.read.schema(schema).csv('file.csv', mode='DROPMALFORMED')`

Comment: @Emma I can't use the above method and it is to be done using pandas. the shaded lines can sometime increase or decrease also.

Comment: @JonSG, Yes they are not just single column it could be multiple as well. just need to delete the lines before reading the actual content i.e. from line#5-line#7

Comment: Outside of python, how do you figure out when the header stops and the data starts and then again where the footer starts. If you can't describe how you figure it out, it will be impossible to automate.

Comment: do you need to use `pandas` or `pyspark`? title and description states `pyspark`.

Comment: @Emma, either works. i'm just looking for some hint on how to identify the header/footer and eliminate them before writing. I have to implement this is pysprak. no issue even if the solution is in python

Comment: @JonSG the header can't be descriobed as how many rows, but the footer always has only two rows at the bottom(i.e. the last two lines). looking for some sort of logic/hint to implement the same

Comment: okay. the code in previous comment should work in pyspark. 1st code is if your header/footer always start with a specific character (ex: #), `comment='#'` will ignore any lines that starts with the letter.  The second code is identifying where is the data instead of identifying the header/footer. It will read any lines that fits the schema and drop any lines doesn't look like the schema(data).